# Kibana 3 - How to bind different query for different panels

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In Kibana , I have made many panels. Currently a single query is working for the entire set of panels. Instead , I would like to keep a different query for each panel and no queries at all for a single panel. How can i do this using Kibana 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have done an example for you using Kibana 3.

[image: Fig 1]

As you can see from fig1,there are 2 queries(red box 1) namely "avengers" and "spiderman" applied in this analytics. And by default this queries are applied to every panel. Here we have the histogram panel (red box 2) with the histogram analytics of the two queries shown in the green and yellow color.Just below the red box 2,you can see the queries listed in corresponding colors.
Now press the "settings" icon (red box 3) situated towards the right of the histogram panel. A new window opens up like in the fig 2 below.

[image: Fig 2]

There select the Queries section (red box 1) and then select the "selected" option from the drop-down (red box 2). Now you can see the queries applied to that panel listed as tabs (red box 3) under the names "selected queries". Now click on anyone of the queries and you can see the clicked one becoming a little smaller,which means that query is no more selected in applying to the current panel. Here i have deselected the "spiderman" query. Now click the save button at the right bottom.
The resulting histogram panel is shown below in fig 3.

[image: Fig 3]

In fig 3 you can clearly see that there is only one set of histogram,and that is of the query "avengers",and the stats of which can be seen from the red box 2 in fig3.
Now if you want to totally remove all the queries,goto settings as mentioned earlier and then unselect all the queries and then click save. Upon doing that,I have received an empty histogram panel as shown below

[image: Fig 4]

Like this you can do for each and every panel and select the required query/queries.